# Is the Crystal Reports .RPT file format specified anywhere?

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there any documentation anywhere as to the structure of the Crystal .RPT file format?

thanks - dave

Comment: what version?  In version 11, if you open the RPT file in a text editor, it is not human readable / structured data

Comment: All recent versions. It's the same format for all of them (new items added with new versions I assume).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Programatically alter the report?

Comment: We want to write a converter to convert a .rpt file to a Windward (my company) template.

Answer (score 2):

Use the free SDK:

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27465

The SDK let's you read all report definition details in your application.

Comment: Unfortunately that cannot be used to convert a RPT file for use by another reporting program.

Comment: Why not? The SDK is free to use.

Comment: Read the license agreement that comes with it. There are restrictions on what it can be used for.

Comment: You can also use the export format "Report Definition" to export the definition to text file and work from there.

Comment: @DavidThielen well user564548  has vanished into the Ether, but you are right... not only about the license agreement, but there are a bunch of dependencies it requires which you basically must have present or it won't work. (as opposed to a specification which works on any language, machine, OS etc. you care to implement it for)

Answer (score 0):

I had to export the report definition manually rather than use a power shell script to read the binary as utf8 and encode it to text.  this was a long process considering the number of reports to export.  I want to do this in batch using powershell then search the text for all stored procedures.

```
$path="C:\\Users\\xxx\Crystal Reports"
set-location $path

Write-Host "Folder: '$path'..." -foregroundColor "green"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.rpt  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force| foreach-object{
    
    $fileAndPath=$_.FullName;
    $fileName=$_.Name;

    $fileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($fileAndPath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
    #$textBuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder


    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($fileStream, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
    #$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($fileStream, [System.Text.Encoding]::Default)
    $bytes = $reader.ReadToEnd()
    $encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
    $text=$encoding.GetString([byte[]]($bytes))

    write-Host $text

    $fileStream.Close()

    #$bytes = Get-Content -Path $fileAndPath -Encoding Byte

    # Convert the bytes to a string
    #$text = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString($bytes)

    $textToFind="brpt"
    if ($text.Contains($textToFind)) {
       # write-Host $text
        Write-Host "File: $fileAndPath '..." -foregroundColor "Magenta"   
    }       
}
```